# Does this Java example cause a memory leak?

Tags: java, memory-leaks

I have a simple example. The example loads an `ArrayList<Integer>` from a file `f` containing 10000000 random integers.

```
doLog("Test 2");
{
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);
    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
    List<Integer> l = (List<Integer>) ois.readObject();
    ois.close();
    fis.close();
    doLog("Test 2.1");
    //l = null; 
    doLog("Test 2.2");
}
doLog("Test 2.3");
System.gc();
doLog("Test 2.4");
```

When I have `l = null`, I get this log:

```
Test 2                          Used Mem = 492 KB   Total Mem = 123 MB
Test 2.1                        Used Mem = 44 MB    Total Mem = 123 MB
Test 2.2                        Used Mem = 44 MB    Total Mem = 123 MB
Test 2.3                        Used Mem = 44 MB    Total Mem = 123 MB
Test 2.4                        Used Mem = 493 KB   Total Mem = 123 MB
```

But when I remove it, I get this log instead.

```
Test 2                          Used Mem = 492 KB   Total Mem = 123 MB
Test 2.1                        Used Mem = 44 MB    Total Mem = 123 MB
Test 2.2                        Used Mem = 44 MB    Total Mem = 123 MB
Test 2.3                        Used Mem = 44 MB    Total Mem = 123 MB
Test 2.4                        Used Mem = 44 MB    Total Mem = 123 MB
```

`Used Memory` is calculated by: `runTime.totalMemory() - runTime.freeMemory()`

**Question:** In case where `l = null;` is present, is there a memory leak?
`l` is inaccessible, so why can't it be freed?

Comment: You didn't use `l`, and the GC can't destroy it in case you could use it later.

Comment: @Uhehesh it is defined in the given scope only, so it cannot be used later on

Comment: Garbage Collection eligibility is not that simple. A given object may need several execution of the garbage collector to become eligible for garbage collection. Also, you have no guarantee that garbage collection will complete after you call System.gc() - it is even guaranteed to run.

Comment: *In case where l = null; is present, is there a memory leak? l is inaccessible, so why can't it be freed?* Reachability has nothing to do w/ the curly brackets you see in java code at all. Actually `l` is unreachable immediately after read (provided os.readObject() doesn't keep a reference 'somewhere' - yes it's possible)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

There is no memory leak in the above code.

As soon as you leave the code block enclosed in `{}`, the variable `l` falls out of scope, and the `List` is a candidate for garbage collection, regardless of if you set it to `null` first or not.

*However*, after the code block and until the return of the method, the `List` is in a state called *invisible*. While this is true, the JVM is unlikely to automatically null out the reference and collect the `List`'s memory. Therefore, explicitly setting `l = null` can help the JVM collect the memory before you do your memory calculations. Otherwise, it will happen automatically when the method returns.

You will probably get different results for different runs of your code, since you never know exactly when the garbage collector will run. You can *suggest* that you think it should run using `System.gc()` (and it might even collect the invisible `List` even without setting `l = null`), but there are no promises. It is stated in the [javadoc for System.gc()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#gc%28%29):

> *Calling the gc method suggests that the Java Virtual Machine expend
>   effort toward recycling unused objects in order to make the memory
>   they currently occupy available for quick reuse. When control returns
>   from the method call, the Java Virtual Machine has made a best effort
>   to reclaim space from all discarded objects.*

Comment: *In case where l = null; is present, is there a memory leak? l is inaccessible, so why can't it be freed?* -- 23 Upvotes and the statement is blatantly wrong. Curly brackets do nothing about reachability of an object whatsoever in java, they won't even change the bytecode. `l` is technically unreachable upon assignment since it is not read afterwards. Setting it to null however would ensure that even if it was kept in a register it'd be ok to be garbaged, provided the JIT doesn't optimize away the write and doesn't optimize away reachability within the method boundaries.

Comment: @bestsss: `l` is a local variable that only lives inside the curly brackets, so they very much influence the reachability of the `List`.

Comment: that works only on source level... on bytecode it's totally different and [reaching definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reaching_definition) in the JIT compiler is even more twisted.

Comment: in other words curly brackets do not anything when the code is compiled.

Comment: @bestsss: I don't think my answer in its previous form was necessarily wrong, but you do bring up an important point. Edited the answer to address this.

Comment: Generally, in the face of lack of optimizations (i.e. interpreted code) you should consider ALL variables in a method reachable. When the code is JIT'd for real reaching-definitions become very important as they govern how the CPU registers are assigned, then you may consider a variable unreachable if it's not read - the case is quite complicated since the control flow could be tricky to optimized well. Other than that `System.gc()` do free up the stuff unless explicitly disabled (for Sun/Oracle's JVM). Quoting javadoc is OK but the issue is mostly practical, it's clear no leak exists.

Answer (score 4):

I think there's a bit of semantics issue here. "Memory leak" generally means having some data stored in memory by a program (piece of software, etc) and getting that program into a state where it can no longer access that in-memory data to clean it up, thus getting into a situation where that memory cannot be claimed for future use. This, as far as I can tell, is the general definition.

A real-world use of the term "memory leak" is usually in reference to programming languages where it's up to the developer to manually allocate memory for the data that he intends to place on the heap. Such languages are C, C++, Objective-C (*), etc. For example the "malloc" command or the "new" operator both allocate memory for an instance of a class that will be placed in the heap memory space. In such languages, a pointer needs to be kept to those thusly allocated instances, if we later-on want to clean up the memory used by them (when they're no longer needed). Continuing on the above example, a pointer referencing an instance that has been created on the heap using "new" can later on be "removed" from memory by using the "delete" command and passing it the pointer as parameter.

Thus, for such languages, a memory leak usually means having data placed on the heap and subsequentlly either:

- arriving into a state where there's no longer a pointer to that data
  or
- forgetting/ignoring to manually "de-allocate" that on-the-heap data (via it's pointer)

Now, in the context of such a definition of "memory leak" this can pretty much never happend with Java. Technically, in Java it's the Garbage Collector's task to decide when heap-allocated instances are no longer referenced or fall out of scope and clean them up. There's no such equivalent of the C++ "delete" command in Java that would even allow the developer to manually "de-allocate" instances/data from the heap. Even making all the pointers of an instance null will not immediatelly free up that instance's memory, but instead it will only make it "garbage collectable" leaving it to the Garbage Collector thread(s) to clean it up when it makes its sweeps.

Now, one other thing that can happen in Java is to never let go of pointers to certain instances, even though they will no longer be needed after a given point. Or, to give certain instance a scope that's too big for what they are used. This way, they will hang around in memory longer than needed (or forever, where forever means until the JDK process is killed) and thus not have them collected by the Garbage Collector even though from a functional stand-point they should be cleaned up. This can lead to behaviour similar to a "memory leak" in the broader sense where "memory leak" simply stands for "having stuff in memory when it's no longer needed and having no way to clean it up".

Now, as you can see, "memory leak" is somewhat vague, but from what I can see, your example doesn't contain a memory leak (even the version where you don't make l=null). All your variables are in a tight scope as delimited by the accolade block, they are used inside that block and will fall out of scope when the block ends, thus they'll be Garbage Collected "properly" (from the functional stand-point of your program). As @Keppil states: making the pointer null will give the GC a better hint as to when to clean up it's corresponding instance, but even if you never make it null, your code will not (un-necessarely) hang on to instances, so no memory leak there.

A typical example of Java memory leak is when having code deployed into a Java EE application server, such that it will spawn threads outside the control of said application server (imaging a servlet that starts a Quartz job). If the application is deployed and undeployed multiple times, it's possible that some of the threads will not be killed at undeploy time, but also (re) started at deploy time, thus leaving them and any instances they might have created hang uselessly in memory.

(*) The later versions of Objective-C also give the possibility to have heap memory managed automatically, in a fashion similar to Javas Garbage Collection mechanism.

Comment: I think in the case of Java, the definition of memory leak is simple: any object that is unintentionally reachable. (And reachability has a proper definition too.)

Comment: No, I meant unintentionally reachable. As Java has a GC, everything that isn't reachable is eligible for collection, therefore is not a memory leak. When you've got stuff that is (strongly) reachable even though it shouldn't be, that's when you get a memory leak.

Comment: It's important because it means you have to do the exact opposite of what you do in C: you should lose all references to objects as quickly as feasible. (Although I'm not a big fan of explicit nulling of local variables, unless it really is necessary or makes the code more readable.)

Comment: You can read this blog post: http://plumbr.eu/blog/what-is-a-memory-leak . I tried to explain there, how can Java, with it GS, still have memory leaks.

Answer (score 2):

The real answer is that unless the code is JIT'd all local variables are 'reachable' within the method body.

Morealso, *curly brackets do absolutely nothing in the bytecode*. They exist only in the source level - JVM is absolutely unaware of them. Setting `l` to null effectively frees the reference up off the stack, so it's GC'd for real. Happy stuff.

If you used another method instead of an inline block everything would have passed w/o any surprises.

If the code is JIT'd and the JVM compiler has built [reaching-definitions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reaching_definition) [(also this)](http://www.azulsystems.com/blog/cliff/2011-08-28-just-fixed-a-20-year-old-bug) most likely setting `l=null` would have no effect and memory be freed in either case.

Comment: For those wishing to verify this answer: [sections 2.6 and 2.6.1 of the JVM spec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.6) states that local variables are discarded when the *method* completes.

Comment: The curly braces __have__ an effect upon the class files: Each local variable is stored in the stack frame in the "Local Variables" section. The curly braces allow to reuse these slots in later code in the same method. This might make the list unreachable earlier. Check this with `javap -v` and check the "LocalVariableTable" section. Also add some other variables after the braces and see show they share the same slot with the stuff inside the braces.

Comment: @A.H., the compiler can reuse slots as it pleases - there is only Object Ref type and primitives. If a variable is unused (i.e. not referenced), the compiler can reuse that slot with or without the curly braces. [this is one ways to confuse decompilers easily]. Point is that curly braces are unavailable for the runtime. Indeed the slots are to be reused if the compiler (not JVM) decides so but there have to be declarations and assignments past the curly braces. On a side note: local var can often be skipped by using enough DUP but javac doesn't compile like that (although I use it myself).

Answer (score 1):

> Question: In case of removing l = null; (do not have this line of
>   code), is this a memory leak?

No, but it *facilitates* the gc in claiming the memory if you do this "pattern"